# Opening a DIV in the HTML as Modal in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

Learning some AngularJS here...

I have an Angular application which connects to an ASP.Net WebAPI.

I am trying to have a DIV inside my HTML open as a modal window.

My HTML looks as follows:

```
<div class="container" style="padding-top:20px;">
    <div ng-app="vehicleApp" data-ng-controller="testingController" class="container">
        <div ng-show="error" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            <p>{{ error }}</p>
        </div>

        <div class="modal fade" id="vehicleModel" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">X</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel" ng-hide="editMode">Add vehicle</h4>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel" ng-show="editMode">Edit vehicle: {{ vehicle.Id }}</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="addvehicleform">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="title" class="col-sm-3 control-label">vehicle Name</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-7">
                                    <input type="text" data-ng-model="vehicle.Name" class="form-control" id="vehiclename" placeholder="vehicle Name" required title="Enter your vehicle Name" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="title" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Identification Account</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-7">
                                    <input type="number" data-ng-model="vehicle.vehicleIdentificationAccountId" class="form-control" id="vehicleIdentificationAccountId" placeholder="vehicle Identification Account" required title="Enter your Identification Account" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-7">
                                    <span data-ng-hide="editMode">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Add" ng-disabled="addvehicleform.$invalid" data-ng-click="add()" class="btn btn-primary normal-button" />
                                    </span>
                                    <span data-ng-show="editMode">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Update" ng-disabled="addvehicleform.$invalid" data-ng-click="update()" class="btn btn-primary normal-button" />
                                    </span>
                                    <input type="button" value="Cancel" data-ng-click="cancel()" class="btn btn-primary" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <h1>Vehicle List</h1>
        <p><a data-ng-click="showadd()" href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-primary">Add New vehicle</a></p>
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Vehicle ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Identification Account</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr data-ng-hide="agencies || agencies.length > 0">
                    <td colspan="4">
                        <div class="text-center text-warning">
                            <strong>No Agencies Retrieved</strong>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr data-ng-repeat="vehicle in agencies">
                    <td>{{vehicle.Id}}</td>
                    <td>{{vehicle.Name}}</td>
                    <td>{{vehicle.vehicleIdentificationAccountId}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a data-ng-click="get(vehicle)" href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-open"></span>View</a>
                        &nbsp;
                        <a data-ng-click="edit(vehicle)" href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>Edit</a>
                        &nbsp;
                        <a data-ng-click="showConfirm(vehicle)" href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <hr />

        <div class="modal fade" id="viewModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">X</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">View vehicle Detail</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="viewuser">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="ID" class="col-sm-3 control-label">ID</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-7">
                                    {{vehicle.Id}}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-7">
                                    {{vehicle.Name}}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="vehicleIdentificationAccountId" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Identification Account</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-7">
                                    {{vehicle.vehicleIdentificationAccountId}}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal fade" id="confirmModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">X</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Confirm</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        Are you sure you want to delete vehicle: {{ vehicle.Name}}?
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-ng-click="delete()" style="width:100px;">Ok</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" style="width:100px;">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

testingController.js

```
'use strict';

app.controller('testingController', function ($scope, testingDataService, $modal) {
    $scope.vehicles = [];
    $scope.vehicle = null;
    $scope.editMode = false;

    // Get vehicle
    $scope.get = function () {
        $scope.vehicle = this.vehicle;
        $('#viewModal').modal('show');
    };

    //get all vehicles
    $scope.getAll = function () {
        testingDataService.getvehicleList().success(function (data) {
            $scope.vehicles = data;
        }).error(function (data) {
            $scope.error = "An Error has occured while Loading vehicles! " + data.ExceptionMessage;
        });
    };

    // add vehicle
    $scope.add = function () {
        var currentvehicle = this.vehicle;
        if (currentvehicle != null && currentvehicle.Name != null && currentvehicle.vehicleIdentificationAccountId!= null) {
            testingDataService.addvehicle(currentvehicle).success(function (data) {
                $scope.addMode = false;
                currentvehicle = data;
                $scope.vehicles.push(currentvehicle);

                //reset form
                $scope.vehicle = null;

                $('#vehicleModel').modal('hide');
            }).error(function (data) {
                $scope.error = "An Error has occured while Adding vehicle! " + data.ExceptionMessage;
            });
        }
    };

    //edit vehicle
    $scope.edit = function () {
        $scope.vehicle = this.vehicle;
        $scope.editMode = true;
        $('#vehicleModel').modal('show');
    };

    //update vehicle
    $scope.update = function () {
        var currentvehicle = this.vehicle;

        testingDataService.updatevehicle(currentvehicle).success(function (data) {
            currentvehicle.editMode = false;

            $('#vehicleModel').modal('hide');
        }).error(function (data) {
            $scope.error = "An Error has occured while Updating vehicle! " + data.ExceptionMessage;
        });
    };

    // delete 
    $scope.delete = function () {
        currentvehicle = $scope.vehicle;
        testingDataService.deletevehicle(currentvehicle).success(function (data) {
            $('#confirmModal').modal('hide');
            $scope.vehicles.pop(currentvehicle);

        }).error(function (data) {
            $scope.error = "An Error has occured while Deleting vehicle! " + data.ExceptionMessage;

            $('#confirmModal').modal('hide');
        });
    };

    //Modal popup events
    $scope.showadd = function () {
        $scope.vehicle = null;
        $scope.editMode = false;
        $('#vehicleModel').modal({ backdrop: 'static' });
        $('#vehicleModel').modal('show');
    };

    $scope.showedit = function () {
        $('#vehicleModel').modal({ backdrop: 'static' });
        $('#vehicleModel').modal('show');
    };

    $scope.showConfirm = function (data) {
        $scope.vehicle = data;
        $('#confirmModal').modal('show');
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $scope.vehicle = null;
        $('#vehicleModel').modal('hide');
    }

    // initialize your users data
    $scope.getAll();
});
```

Basically when I click on the Add New Vehicle button, the console says:

**ReferenceError: $ is not defined**

on the line in the controller where it is supposed to show the modal:

```
$('#vehicleModel').modal({ backdrop: 'static' });
```

I am a bit lost on how to resolve this.

Appreciate any insight.

P.S. The data loads fine when this HTML view is loaded up. I also added a console.log inside the

```
$scope.showadd = function (){
  console.log('Test');
};
```

and that is logged properly in the console. So totally lost right now...

Update:
Did a little more investigation. I issued in Chrome console the command:

```
$('#vehicleModel')
```

and it showed me the div with the id=vehicleModel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would argue that you should probably be using Angular UI Bootstrap to create your modal dialogs. [Here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) is the link.

Here is a cut down version of how to open a modal using Angular UI Bootrstrap:

```
$scope.open = function (vehicle) {

  var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
    resolve: {
      items: function () {
        return $scope.items;
      }
    }
  });

};
```

**MODAL CONTENT**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Modal!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div >Body</div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$close('awesome')">OK</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="$dismiss('nah')">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<a data-ng-click="open(vehicle)" href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-open"></span>View</a>
```

Comment: I'd love to try this at some point, but for now, I'd want to understand why my DIV is not showing up as a modal.

Comment: Using jQuery directly in an angular controller is not generally recommended. If you do, it's best to wrap it in a directive. Your div is not showing up because you likely have a namespace collision. But if you really want to use jQuery to create your div, you can look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967434/what-is-the-best-practice-for-opening-a-jquery-dialog-from-angular

Comment: I think I may have actually tried to use AngularUI Bootstrap, but wasn't able to make it work properly. Here's a link to a question I posted about it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25857347/closing-a-modal-in-angularjs-ui

Comment: Added an answer to that. Hopefully it works for you.

Comment: i think this is a better approach, so I've upvoted it

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to grab your element the jQuery way. $ is reserved in Angular. try using:

```
angular.element('div').modal({ backdrop: 'static' });
```

where 'div' is whatever your actual tag name is, and traverse the DOM for it...

EDIT: from https://docs.angularjs.org/error/jqLite/nosel

> In order to resolve this error, rewrite your code to only use tag name selectors and manually traverse the DOM using the APIs provided by jqLite.
>
> Alternatively, you can include a full version of jQuery, which Angular
>   will automatically use and that will make all selectors available.

Comment: Got an error: Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite!

Comment: I've included a reference to jQuery 1.10.2 and I still have the same error. Really stumped on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can code like this:

```
 // Pre-fetch an external template populated with a custom scope
  var myOtherModal = $modal({scope: $scope, template: 'modal/docs/modal.demo.tpl.html', show: false});
  // Show when some event occurs (use $promise property to ensure the template has been loaded)
  $scope.showModal = function() {
    myOtherModal.$promise.then(myOtherModal.show);
  };
```